# Logstash datefilte not matching

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, datefilter

I have a problem with logstash date filter. I have a date field like  `"\"date\"" => "\"2021-03-18 11:00:00\""",` and I want to use it to replace the basic @timestamp of logstash, so i added the date filter in the logstash config file like :  `date {match => ["date","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]}`  but nothing happened.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: That looks like you have a field called ["date"], with double quotes in the name. Likewise the value. You could try `date {match => ['"date"','"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"']}`

Comment: Hi, thank you it works !  but 2021-03-18 11:00:00 is seen as  2021 03 18 at 00:00 , do you know why it's not taking the right time (11:00) ?  (in elastic logs it is seen as 2021-03-18T10:00:00.000Z )  thank you again

Comment: it's ok I think I understand, now working properly , thank you again